# I'm curious about the c language printf format output value

Tags: c, printf

I have a question while studying C language.

```
printf("%d, %f \n", 120, 125.12);
```

The output value in this code is:

```
120, 125.120000
```

That's it. And

```
printf("%d, %f \n", 120.1, 125.12);
```

The output value of this code is:

```
1717986918, 0.000000
```

That's it.

Of course, I understand that the output value of %d in front of us was a strange value because I put a mistake in the integer format character. But I don't know why %f is 0.000000 after that. Does the character on the back have an effect on the value of the previous character?

I'm asking because I'm curious because it keeps coming out like this even if I put in a different price.

Comment: Is the missing comma intended ?

Comment: Sorry, There was a typo.
The questions are the same.

Comment: `printf("%d, %f \n", 120.1, 125.12);` on my system reports an understandable "format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’" warning, but spits out `-176207768, 120.100000` (as expected)

Comment: For `%d`, printf will assume the type of the argument is `int`, but you provide a `double` constant. If these types have different sizes on your platform (which is likely), then printf will read from the wrong address for `%f`

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is a variadic function, meaning its argument types and counts are variable.  As such, they must be extracted according to their type. Extraction of a given argument is dependent on the proper extraction of the arguments that precede it.  Different argument types have different sizes, alignments, etc.

If you use an incorrect format specifier for a `printf` argument, then it throws `printf` out of sync.  The arguments after the one that was incorrectly extracted will not, in general, be extracted correctly.

In your example, it probably extracted only a portion of the first `double` argument that was passed, since it was expecting an `int` argument.  After that it was out of sync and improperly extracted the second `double` argument.  This is speculative though, and varies from one architecture to another.  The behavior is undefined.

Comment: If I am right, all arguments are converted to `int` or `double`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Only some types are.  Small signed integers are converted to `int`, and `float` is converted to `double`.  But larger integer types are not converted to `int`, `unsigned` is passed as `unsigned`.  There are also pointer types, and larger-than-double floating point types.

Answer (score 2):

> why %f is 0.000000 after that.

According to the C standard because `%d` expects an `int` and you passed a `double`, undefined behavior happens and anything is allowed to happen.

Anyway:
I used http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html to convert doubles to bits:

```
120.1  === 0x405E066666666666 
125.12 === 0x405F47AE147AE148
```

I guess that your platform is x86-ish, little endian, with ILP32 data model.

The `%d` printf format specifier is for `int` and `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes or 32 bits in LP64. Because the architecture is little endian and the stack too, the first 4 bytes from the stack are `0x66666666` and the decimal value of it is printed out which is `1717986918`.

On the stack are left three 32-bit little endian words, let's split them `0x405E0666 0x147AE148 0x405F47AE`.

The `%f` `printf` format specifier is for `double` and `sizeof(double)` on your platform is 8 or 64 bits. We already read 4 bytes from the stack, and now we read 8 bytes. Remembering about the endianess, we read `0x147AE148405E0666` that is converted to double. Again I used [this site](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=147AE148405E0666) and converted the hex to a double, it resulted in `5.11013578783948654276686949883E-210`. `E-210` - this is a very, very small number. Because `%f` by default prints with 6 digits of precision, the initial 7 digits of the number are 0, so only zeros are printed. If you would use `%g` printf format specifier, then the number would be printed as `5.11014e-210`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be attributed to the fact that the `printf` function is not type-safe, i.e. there is no connection between the specifiers in the format string and the passed arguments.

The function converts all integer arguments to `int` (4 bytes) and all floats to `double` (8 bytes). As the types are guessed from the format string, a shift in the data occurs. It is likely that the `0.000000` appears because what is loaded corresponds to a floating-point zero (biaised exponent = 0).

Try with `1.0, 1.e34`.